# Symbolic links with Git on Windows not triggering UAC prompt

Tags: windows, git, symlink

Git for Windows apparently now implements support for symbolic links on NTFS filesystems. ([See this git wiki page.](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/Symbolic-Links))

On windows, creating symlinks is an administrator privilege by default. The wiki page explains how to give the necessary permissions to normal users. (Under the heading: "Allowing non-administrators to create symbolic links")

My problem is, that even after following this, git does not create symlinks but fails with:

`error: unable to create symlink somefile.h: Permission denied`

The wiki page mentions the need for UAC elevation, but the UAC prompt is never triggered.

Has anybody gotten this to work?

Comment: but are you ask UAC elevation ?

Comment: @RbMm As I wrote, I am never asked for UAC elevation. I do not know why the UAC prompt is never triggered.

Comment: it and not must be, of you direct not ask

Comment: @RbMm I am afraid I do not understand what you write.

Comment: add manifest to your app with `<requestedExecutionLevel level='requireAdministrator'/>` - will be uac promt. look like you nothing know about how uac worked

Comment: Git 2.23 might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57084394/6309

Comment: @ARF several years later, and I am having the exact same experience. I followed the wiki, and yet I get the same "permission denied". I can run a terminal As Administrator, and then it succeeds (I can clone a git repo with links that properly turn into windows-style links, and my application behaves as I wish when it is cloned this way). But I do not wish to Run As Administrator in the terminal where I invoke my git commands. Would still love an answer to this Q....

Comment: Moderate progress/success. Ok, so on Windows 10 I just searched for "enable developer mode", and once I enabled Developer Mode in my Windows settings I am able to git clone with symlinks as my normal user.  On the one hand, this does represent "success". However, I do worry that by running in this exotic mode, I will be out of touch with what a normal Windows user will experience, and therefore be out of touch with my customers. But I guess that just means I need a clean customer-test machine, which of course I already have. So I guess I succeeded :/